# why can't i attach a process in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

when i am trying to attach a process(w3wp.exe)  in asp.net (visual studio 2008), i couldn't attach it , it displays the following error

[image: error while attaching a process]

i have repaired the visual studio 2008, after seen this. again i got the same error as shown above when  i am trying to attach a new one.
why this happens, is i need to download any other service pack or visual studio 2008 remote debugger installation ( as mentioned in the error box),.  please help me to fix it.

Comment: what iis/web server you use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/0528bc98-095e-4ff8-af6e-e92b89ba54ae/), there should be a remote debugger setup file on the VS2008 disc in a folder called "Remote Debugger\x64" or "WCU\RDBG\x64".

You could also try downloading and installing the [Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 Remote Debugger](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10647).

Comment: i couldn't find  the folder in vs8, what to do now? will i need to download anything..|?

Comment: @Gomathipriya: Try downloading and executing the file given on the Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 Remote Debugger page I linked in my answer.